# Word or phrase that means to ascertain whether someone is alive or dead

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

*Diagnose* comes close to this meaning, but the result of a diagnosis is not usually a binary classification. I'd like a word or phrase that means to determine whether someone is alive or dead, or analogously, a word or phrase that means to determine whether a device is functioning or broken.

Comment: I think "check vital state" is about as succinct as you'll find.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no singular word for this.

Comment: [World's funniest joke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World's_funniest_joke#The_jokes) has the answer!

Comment: What @Mr.Wizard said is perhaps most technically correct, but "check vital signs" is probably a more common phrase (in my experience, American).

Comment: @Lynn I never understand why people think there is a single word for everything. After all, what’s the single word for making a single-word request? :)

Comment: How about `kill`? You've then ascertained whether they are alive or dead; they are dead. :-)

Comment: @tchrist:  Maybe you should submit that as a question?   :)  J/K

Comment: @tchrist, why are people so hung up on the "single" in the [single-word-request] tag? That's just our administrative way to mark reverse dictionary type questions; unless the asker specifically says so, don't assume that they'll only accept single-word answers.

Comment: @Marthaª  Because that’s what the tag wiki says, that’s why!  Perhaps you could please edit it to reflect your broader understanding.

Comment: Yeah, that's actually quite true. There's also a [phrase-requests] tag. I suppose I should use both here? P.S. Just added it.

Comment: What's a single word for adding the phrase "or a phrase" to what was originally a single-word request?  (I'll accept a phrase.)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure there is a single word for this- 'triage' is possibly more apt than diagnose as it has more of a sense of life and death. However, it also does not result in a binary classification.

Comment: Probably still a good choice, since it means "to sort" and has a medical context. Presumably a device which is "not dead" will have a further sort applied to it. There is an image of a triage tag on the wikipedia page which, if modified slightly, would be perfect for use with devices.

Comment: I don't think this really fits. See jwpat7's comment below. "Triage" means classifying people for priority of treatment. Anyone who's already dead wouldn't be included in a triage.

Comment: @Jay: As emergency responders, the basic triage we're taught includes a category for dead/moribund (black tag).

Answer (score 2):

*Triage* ("the process of determining the priority of patients' treatments based on the severity of their condition ... from the French verb *trier*, meaning to separate, sift or select") has been mentioned, but I'll write a bit more about it anyway.  The [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triage) on *triage* says

> At its most primitive, those responsible for the removal of the wounded from a battlefield ... have divided victims into three categories:
>   • Those who are likely to live, regardless of what care they receive;
>   • Those who are likely to die, regardless of what care they receive;
>   • Those for whom immediate care might make a positive difference in outcome.

Techniques of triage are taught in medical school (during emergency-room or critical-care rotations) to allow coping with catastrophes.

Answer (score 2):

For devices in computer networks, **ping** is the common word.

> Ping the server to find if it's busy.

For human beings, **check** or **check up** stands for this meaning and is also easily understandable.

> The doctor checked his pulse to ascertain his death.

Comment: Ping sounds like a good word. I'm actually asking this question to get find a good variable name. I first wanted to name it EmailTracerRound - an email that checks to see if the email is going to the right place, but I decided that the reference might not be universally understandable.

Comment: @MatthewPiziak: I do not know the spec details, but does EmailTracker fit your purpose?

Comment: ping bre.a.t.hin' will give you 100% packet loss

Comment: @Shyam It would probably suffice, but it's actually a service that sends an email every so often to check if the email routing works. CheckEmail is probably the best name I can think of so far.

Comment: What if you were to ping someone to death? What then?

Comment: You might find the book about Ping useful; see review by [Fracisco](http://www.amazon.com/review/R2VDKZ4X1F992Q/ref=cm_cr_dp_title?ie=UTF8&ASIN=0140502416&nodeID=283155&store=books), which says "Using deft allegory, the authors have provided an insightful and intuitive explanation of one of Unix's most venerable networking utilities. Even more stunning is that they were clearly working with a very early beta of the program, as their book first appeared ... before the operating system and network infrastructure were finalized."

Comment: I don't think _check_ works, not by itself, but I do think _check for a pulse_ is a nice idiomatic way to describe the process of checking whether something is dead or alive.  It might even work for non-living things: _Newsweek magazine recently indicated that its print edition doesn't have much of a pulse left_.

Answer (score 1):

It's not one word, but **viability check** may fit your bill

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a one-word answer that means to check if somebody is alive or dead. However, if [triage](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/triage) will not fit the bill, then you can consider [palpation](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palpation), which is "*the act of feeling or pushing on various parts of a patient’s body to determine medical condition such as the normality of organs or the presence or absence of tumors, swelling, muscle tension, etc.*". I've listed it here as, unlike *diagnosis* which is about identifying the cause of an illness, *palpation* is more about *checking* if something is wrong (or not). It, however, isn't applicable when it comes to checking for life or death.

Palpation is similar to [diagnosis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diagnosis), albeit accomplished solely through touch, and is something performed *as part of a* diagnosis. A verb, [palpate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/palpate), also exists. It is not to be confused with *palpitate* or *palpitation* which are quite different.

The image below is [captioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palpation) "*Palpation of a man's chest*":

[image: Palpation of a man's chest]

Incidentally, while checking to see if there was something along the lines of *vitametry* or *vitameter*, I came across a company named "LifeScan" peddling a glucometer under the moniker of "[One Touch Vita meter](http://www.lifescan.co.uk/ourproducts/meter/one-touch-vita)".

Comment: This looks more like a routine checkup; I don't really think he's making sure that guy is alive. :^)

Comment: @J.R. I suggest that you also _read_ the answer :)